# Laravel 5.8 listener event doesn't work at server

Tags: php, laravel, events, design-patterns, listener

For some reasons Listener not worked at server, but at local machine all is good. I made 3 Log points - at controller,at event and at listener. "Fire event" point and "Event file" are ok, but "Send SMS" dont work. What it can be?

Listener

```
$user = User::find($event->userId);
    if (!is_null($user->phone_verified_at)) {
        Log::info('Send SMS', (array) $user);
        PhoneSms::sendSMS($user->phone, trans(config('sms.'.$event->type)), true);
    }
```

Event

```
public function __construct($userId, $type)
{
    Log::info('Event file', (array) $userId);
    $this->userId = $userId;
    $this->type = $type;
}
```

Controller

```
Log::info('Fire event', (array) $user);
event(new UserDataChanged($user_id, 'not_success_enter'));
```